# local parametrization of regular surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

I am doing excercises of Do Carmo's dg of curves and surfaces Chapter 2.2 and need some help with the following excercise:

Show that the set $S=\{(x,y,z)\in R^3;z=x^2-y^2\}$ a regular surface and check (a) and (b) are parametrizations of $S$. Also : answer: which part of S do these parametrizations 
cover?

(a) $x(u,v)=(u+v,u-v,4uv),(u,v)\in R^2$

(b) $x(u,v)=(u \cosh v, u \sinh v, u^2), (u,v)\in R^2 , u\neq 0$

Part (a) is straightforward. Since S is a regular surface, by prop 2.2.4 it suffices to chek x is differentiable , one-to-one and  and differential is one-to-one. And it's quite straightforward to check these properties. Also, a should cover the whole $S$.

However, for (b) although x is differentiable and I can check that dx is one-to-one, x is simply not one-to-one and hence not a homeomorphism. I am wondering if there's any other definition for local coordinates (or parametrization) so that we don't need one-to-one propert. For example , I only need to show it is locally homeomorphic.Also, I am not quite sure which part of $S$ that x in (b) covers?

Comment: Are you sure $\mathbf{x}$ is not one-to-one in (b)? (For finding the image, it's helpful to consider $u>0$ and $u<0$ separately.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I thought it's true that X in (b)is locally one-to-one and locally homeomorphic. But I dont think x in (b) covers all of S and I want to know exactly which part it covers.

Comment: Certainly the mapping $\mathbf{x}$ is not _onto_ $S$: the third component $u^2$ is positive. (Note, though, that $\mathbf{x}$ _is_ one-to-one.) Thinking of the first two components of $\mathbf{x}$ as "hyperbolic polar coordinates" should help you see what the image is.